# Little strange issue on a simple js

Tags: javascript, injected-class-name

I've got a little problem on a simple script
It applies a className only one time on two.
here is my code. Thanks by advance to all community and, please forgive the poor english of a french guy :-) !

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .alpha{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="RemoveClass('alpha','alpha')">
<div class="myclass alpha">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Fuga, cum!</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Sed, ducimus!</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Veritatis, id.</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="myclass alpha">Ullam, soluta.</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddClass(elem, ClassSupp){
        var Selection = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
        for (var i = 0; i < Selection.length; i++) {
            if (Selection[i].className.indexOf(ClassSupp) == -1){
                Selection[i].className = Selection[i].className + " " + ClassSupp;
            }
        }
    }
    function RemoveClass(elem, ClassSupp){
        var Selection = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
        for (var i = 0; i < Selection.length; i++) {
            Selection[i].className = "Test";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The node list returned from `getElementsByClassName()` is "live". That means that when you remove the class from an element, the element immediately disappears from the list. Thus `Selection[i]` becomes, effectively, `Selection[i+1]`, so the next time you increment `i` you skip an element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer :-) !